# Batch processing in Photoshop executed in a strange order (not alpha-numeric)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have a bunch of files named "lorem1@2x.png, lorem2@2x.png, lorem3@2x.png... ...lorem11@2x.png"

When I try to batch process them, they start at the 10th file, then goes on to the 11th, looping around back to the first file. Why is it doing this and how can I ensure the correct processing order?

Comment: Its doing it in alphabetical order char by char.

Comment: I'm curious, why does the order matter? Isn't the end result the same no matter what the file order is in a batch process?

Comment: It's because I'm naming the files with serial labels. I'm taking lorem1@2x.png, changing it and saving it as lorem(#).png. In order to remove the @2x, I have to rename the file completely to lorem + (1, 2, 3...)

Comment: You did get your problem solved apparently, but since Photoshop is not super ideal for this, I would use a batch renaming application for that. --- Adobe Bridge has a batch renaming feature. There's a `string substitution` preset which would be perfect for that. --- If that is not an option, there are also many batch renaming applications for mac, and I believe for windows as well. I prefer free [NameChanger](http://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/). It has a `replace first occurrence with`, which would work for this _( I'm sure every batch renaming application has similar functionality. )_

Comment: I'll look into that if I ever need to do more extensive renaming. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your files with leading zeros for the variable number (i.e. lorem01@2x.png or lorem100@2x.png).  If you have less than 100 files, two-digit numbers will do.  If you have less than 1000 files, three digits will do.  And so on.

Files will batch in the same order they appear when sorted by name in Explorer (or Finder on Mac).

Comment: Correction: not true for Macs.  My bad.  :)

Comment: Finder might not use the same rules for name order, but leading with zeros fixes it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually newer windows do the number globbing sort, which is different form what PS uses. There are some advantages and dnownsides with both approaches. At the moment the number globbing method is causing me LOT of grief.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred for me - which was caused by the "Save As" action step.  Instead of using the default file name, I had created a custom name.  When calling this action in the batch process Photoshop was continually using this naming convention instead of its default - 'write new' process.  So, remove any custom naming in the 'save as' action and your problem will be resolved.